# button to browse and upload a photo from user's PC,

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

how can I put a button to browse and upload a photo from user's PC, and make it hidden until the user choose a specific value from the previous dropdown list?

This is my previous dropdown list

```
<tr>
      <td style="padding:26px;">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
             <asp:ListItem> long visit  </asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem> Short Visit </asp:ListItem>
             </asp:DropDownList>
      </td>
      <td style="padding:18px;"> Type of Visit </td>         
</tr>
```

so when the user chose Long Visit from the previous dropdown list a browse button for uploading his photo Will appear

Comment: In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve minimal, complete, and verifiable example. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592 tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask how to ask good questions, and take the http://stackoverflow.com/tour tour of the site. :)

Answer (score 0):

add event listener for DropDownList1_OnSelectedIndexChanged and write these code

```
if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex== 0)//index of long visit
    Button1.Visible = true;
else
    Button1.Visible = false;
```

add AutoPostBack="True" to your DropDown

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />  
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Upload" 
  onclick="Button1_Click"/>  
<br />  
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {  
        //get the file name of the posted image  
        string imgName = FileUpload1.FileName;  
        //sets the image path  
        string imgPath = "ImageStorage/" + imgName;            
       //get the size in bytes that  

       int imgSize = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;  

       //validates the posted file before saving  
        if (FileUpload1.PostedFile != null && FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName != "") {  
           // 10240 KB means 10MB, You can change the value based on your requirement  
                if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 10240) {  
                           Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "Alert", "alert('File is too big.')", true);  
                 }  else {  
                           //then save it to the Folder  
                           FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(imgPath));  
                           Image1.ImageUrl = "~/" + imgPath;  
                           Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "Alert", "alert('Image saved!')", true);  
                }   
}
```

[check this link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/asp-net-webforms-uploading-and-validating-and-displaying-images)

Comment: thank you , and how I can add a button to browse and upload a photo from user's PC?